# Replace a value by its preceding in a column R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a dataframe, where I'm trying to replace values in a column, if they're lesser than their preceding ones as shown in the example below, with their preceding ones. I know how to replace NA's but I'm confused with this condition.

```
Present column:

0.1
0.1
0.1
0.01
1

Required column:

0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  It will ensure that column `x` is non-decreasing:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 1)) # test data

transform(DF, x = cummax(x))
```